# Deleted google app engine entities, realized it was a mistake in some cases

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

I accidentally deleted a bunch of entities earlier today in Google App Engine and found out later that some of them should not have been deleted.  I have the keys for the entities I deleted as well as a lot of information about the entities stored in a secondary database.  I was wondering if there was any way to create entities with specific keys in app engine or if there was alternative method of recovering these entities?  I am very worried

Comment: I doubt it. You can contact Google's support, or restore from your backups. In the future, you might consider [object versioning](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/object-versioning) to permit this.

Answer (score 3):

> I was wondering if there was any way to create entities with specific keys in app engine

You can create new entities with those same keys, just set the key property on the instance of the model before you put and it will use that key instead of generating a random one for you.

Also, check if your team has used datastore admin to take snapshots, if so, you may be able to recover them from there: 
https://console.cloud.google.com/datastore/settings